# set images in grid of react dropzone uploaders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, dropzone.js

I am confused in setting custom preview as like
[image set in grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ssI.png)

I want to do this in `react-dropzone-uploader` custom preview, where I can upload multiple files.

Current scenario: [my normal uploaded images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhToc.png)

Code snippet:

```js
const Preview = ({ meta }: IPreviewProps) => {
    const { name, percent, status, previewUrl } = meta ;
    return (
        <Grid item xs={6}>    
            <div className="preview-box">
                <img src={previewUrl} /> <span className="name">{name}</span> - <span className="status">{status}</span>{status !== "done" && <span className="percent"> ({Math.round(percent)}%)</span>}
            </div>
        </Grid>
    )
}
<Dropzone
      getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      PreviewComponent={Preview}
      inputContent="Drop Files"
    />
```

I am using MUI V4
We don't have any index for images, how can I set images in grid view of 2-2 images using material UI?

Comment: Do you use MUI v5 or v4? And could you post the parent of the `Preview` component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the Grid items inside the Grid container.
Please have a look at the guide. https://mui.com/components/grid/

```
// Parent PreviewContainer.js

...
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {
    images.map((image, i) => (
      <PreviewItem key={i} meta={meta} />
    ))
  }
</Grid>
...

// Child PreviewItem.js

...
<Grid item xs={4}>
  // You can update the item size as you expect, but it seems like it should be 4 regarding the image attached
  // Your preview component
</Grid>
...
```